# Calling wget from make based on a pattern

Tags: make, wget

I'm using `make` to grab a set of files that are updated daily on a Web site. What I'd like to do is place the files into a folder named with the date, and then use make to do other processing on the file. I tried this:

```
SUFFIXES = .csv
FILES = file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
BASE_DIR = some/dir
DATE = $(shell date +"%Y%m%d")
SOURCE_FILES = $(patsubst %,$(BASE_DIR)/$(DATE)/%,$(FILES))
ACTIVE_FILES = $(patsubst %,$(BASE_DIR)/%,$(FILES))

all: $(BASE_DIR)/$(DATE) $(ACTIVE_FILES)

$(BASE_DIR)/%.csv: $(BASE_DIR)/$(DATE)/%.csv
    rm -f $@
    ln $(BASE_DIR)/$(DATE)/%

$(BASE_DIR)/$(DATE):
    mkdir $@

$(BASE_DIR)/$(DATE)/%.csv:
    cd $(BASE_DIR)/$(DATE); wget http://example.com/data/%.csv
```

The problem is the last line. I don't know how to pass the filename to wget, since "%.csv" isn't valid in this context. How do I accomplish what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use automatic variable `$*`. From GNU make's documentation:

> `$*`
>
> The stem with which an implicit rule matches. If the target is
>   `dir/a.foo.b` and the target pattern is `a.%.b` then the stem is
>   `dir/foo`. The stem is useful for constructing names of related
>   files.  In a static pattern rule, the stem is part of the file name
>   that matched the `%` in the target pattern.

In your specific case, the wget rule could be rewritten as:

```
$(BASE_DIR)/$(DATE)/%.csv:
    cd $(BASE_DIR)/$(DATE); wget http://example.com/data/$*.csv
```