# Command line tool to check when a URL was updated?

Tags: command-line, web

It would certainly be possible to whip together something in Python to query a URL to see when it was last modified, using the HTTP headers, but I wondered if there is an existing tool that can do that for me? I'd imagine something like:

```
% checkurl http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247445/
Fri Dec  4 16:59:28 EST 2015
```

or maybe:

```
% checkurl "+%Y%m%d" http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247445/
20151204
```

as a bell and/or whistle. I don't think that wget or curl have what I need, but I wouldn't be surprised to be proven wrong. Is there anything like this out there?

Comment: `curl --head url` seems to report the headers to me. Assuming a `Last-Modified` header does come through,  `curl --header url | awk '/Last-Modified/{print $2}'` should be able to extract the value

Comment: Note, though, that `Last-Modified` headers are completely useless on many sites because the pages are generated dynamically from a database and will always return a LM header of approximately now.  This is often done deliberately as a cache-busting technique and to force re-fetches (and thus marketable page views) when the client requests the page with an If-Modified-Since request header.

Comment: That's true enough. My particular use case is to monitor Web-based downloads of databases, so that's less of an issue. Still something to be mindful of, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to fit your requirements (updated to use '\r\n' as record separator for response data):

```
#!/bin/sh

get_url_date()
{
    curl --silent --head "${1:?URL ARG REQUIRED}" | 
    awk -v RS='\r\n' '
        /Last-Modified:/ {
            gsub("^[^ ]*: *", "")
            print
            exit
        }
    '
}

unset date_format
case $1 in
    (+*)
        date_format="$1"
        shift
        ;;
esac

url_date="$(get_url_date "${1:?URL ARG REQUIRED}")"

if [ -z "$url_date" ]
then
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$date_format" != "" ]
then
    date "$date_format" -d"$url_date"
else
    echo "$url_date"
fi
```

Comment: See also `tail -n+2 | formail -zx last-modified` to extract header values (`tail` skipping the response line)

Answer (score 2):

A Perl one-liner:

```
% perl -MLWP::Simple -MDate::Format -e 'print time2str "%C\n", (head $ARGV[0])[2]' http://example.com
Sat Aug 10 02:54:35 EEST 2013
```

On a modern Linux or FreeBSD system the modules it requires are likely to be already installed.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that curl and wget can both do this, but it's probably worth doing in Python after all. Here's what I ended up writing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, dateutil.parser, subprocess, requests
from getopt import getopt

errflag = 0
gTouch = None
gUsage = """Usage: lastmod [-t file] url
where:
-t file     Touches the given file to make its modification date
            the same as the URL modification date.
url         A URL to be retrieved
"""

opts, args = getopt(sys.argv[1:], "t:v?")

for k, v in opts:
    if k == "-t":           # File to touch
        gTouch = v
    elif k == "-?":         # Write out usage and exit
        errflag += 1

if len(args) != 1:
    errflag += 1

if errflag:
    sys.stderr.write(USAGE)
    sys.exit(1)

res = requests.head(args[0])

if res.status_code != 200:
    sys.stderr.write("Failed to retrieve URL\n")
    sys.exit(1)

if not 'Last-Modified' in res.headers:
    sys.stderr.write("Headers has no last-modified date\n")
    sys.exit(1)

dt = dateutil.parser.parse(res.headers['Last-Modified'])

if gTouch:
    subprocess.call(["touch", "-t", dt.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%m"), gTouch])
else:
    sys.stdout.write("%s\n" % dt.ctime())
```

Comment: You really want the [requests] (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module

Comment: I agree in principle, but the above only grabs the header, which is what I really wanted, and it looks like request.get() grabs the whole document, which I really don't want. In fact, using requests does seem to take a LOT longer. If I've got it wrong, would you mind posting a snippet that illustrates how just to check the header?

Comment: Sure. `requests.get('http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247445/').headers['Last-Modified']`

Comment: But does the call to get() retrieve the whole document as well as the headers, or is the retrieval of the document itself postponed until it's required?

Comment: Good point..although I'm approaching the limit of my http knowledge, this should do the job `requests.head('http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247445/').headers['Last-Modified']`

Comment: Ah, there we go. That's working with comparable speed to the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Carbon14; it is a command-line python tool for detecting webpage history from images. If there are some images on your inspecting webpage, it works fine.
Install from [Carbon14 Github repository](https://github.com/Lazza/Carbon14), after installation run with;

```
python carbon14.py <url>
```