# URL dependency in make

Tags: make, wget

I need a dependency in a Makefile that fires if a URL has been updated since the file that depends on it. The situation is a bit complicated:

- URL 1 points to a download page. I want the rule to be dependent upon the last modified date of this page.
- The page contents of URL 1 have an embedded URL pointing to the actual file I want to download (call that URL 2).

I've written a Python script ([lastmod](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247452/command-line-tool-to-check-when-a-url-was-updated)) that will create (by calling "touch") a file with the same modification date as a URL. So the `Makefile` now looks something like this:

```
output_file: .input_url source_file
    wc -l source_file > $@

source_file: .input_url
    wget -q -O $@ --no-use-server-timestamps `cat .input_url`

.input_url: .input_modified
    wget -q -O - $(DOWNLOAD_URL) | \
    sed -n '1,/current version/d;\
           /Previous versions/,$$d;
           s/.*href="\\([^"]*\\):,*/\\1/p' > $@
    lastmod -t $@ $(DOWNLOAD_URL)

.input_modified: FORCE
    lastmod -t $@ $(DOWNLOAD_URL)

FORCE:
```

where DOWNLOAD_URL is set to the download page. The gist is that I want .input_url to be generated only if the download page has been modified since it was created. To do that, I need to always regenerate .input_modified, but have .input_url generated only if the (newly generated) .input_modified has a later mod time. I'm not seeing how to separate the notions of "run this rule" from "tell things that depend on this rule to run". If I leave out "FORCE", then the rule for .input_modified doesn't run. If I put it in, it always runs, but so does the rule for .input_url. Is there any way to accomplish what I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to define an [order-only-prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html#Prerequisite-Types) over the *.input_modified* target, this carries out the *if modified* test,

```
output_file: .input_url source_file
    wc -l source_file > $@

source_file: .input_url
    wget -q -O $@ --no-use-server-timestamps `cat .input_url`

.input_url: .input_modified
    wget -q -O - $(DOWNLOAD_URL) | \
    sed -n '1,/current version/d;\
           /Previous versions/,$$d;
           s/.*href="\\([^"]*\\):,*/\\1/p' > $@
    lastmod -t $@ $(DOWNLOAD_URL)

.input_modified: | if_modified_test    # as order-only-prerequisite

.PHONY: if_modified_test               # test it
if_modified_test: 
    lastmod -t .input_modified $(DOWNLOAD_URL)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about order-only prerequisites.